# Read response data in network events of the JxBrowser

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

I'm trying to fetch the network data from the JxBrowser component (EDIT: it's version 5.4) in my Java application using [Network Events](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013108-network-events):

```java
BrowserContext browserContext = BrowserContext.defaultContext();

browserContext.getNetworkService().setNetworkDelegate(new DefaultNetworkDelegate() {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(RequestCompletedParams var) {
    // var.getResponseBody() // does not exist
    System.out.println("Requested " + var.getURL());
  }
});

Browser browser = new Browser(browserContext);
browser.loadURL("https://www.example.org/");
```

I can obtain the URL of all completed requests and print it into the terminal, however there is no function like `getResponseBody()` to fetch the body data.

The aim is to read the response data of several AJAX calls from within the Host of the JxBrowser component. I'm unable to modify or access the website, directly.

Comment: From skimming the documentation, one possibility I found would be overriding `NetworkDelegate#onDataReceived(DataReceivedParams)` and appending the chunks of data from the `DataReceivedParams#getData()` into a single list for each request.

Comment: @MasterBlaster Thanks. I tried to implement this just to find out that `onDataReceived` does not exist on the interface, because this seems to be version 5.4. I could try to port the lib to version 6, but maybe this is possible in version 5.4, too?

Comment: There is no public documentation available for versions below 6, so I cannot say if it is possible in that version. Additionally, versions below 6 are not hosted in their Maven repository. I have some example code that compiles (I don't have a license to run it) for version 6.24.3 if you are willing to upgrade.

Comment: @MasterBlaster Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade. :/